# Firefox cannot play mp4 under <video> tag but success in Chrome

Tags: html, firefox, video

Why I failed to play the 1st LINKED mp4 video but 
success in 2nd LINKED mp4 video in firefox 45.0.2 (newest already)?

Chrome can play both successfully.

What's the problem?

```
<html>
<body>
    <!-- Failed -->
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="http://video.appledaily.com.hk/admedia/20160413/12042016_int_09new_w.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <!-- Success -->
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <!-- Success and the mp4 is downloaded from 1st link -->
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="12042016_int_09new_w.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does console says?

Comment: `All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.`